# Correct way of doing a Feature Union of TFidf and custom class returning a numeric list

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to achieve doing a feature union performing tfidf on a training data consisting of sentences. Along with that I wish to perform some computation on the sentences to get certain features which will return numeric values.

In the OtherFeatures class I need to understand how the fit and transform function need to be defined so that I could train on a data and cluster accordingly for test data.

```
class OtherFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):       
    def OtherFeatures(self,input):
        ret = []
        for i in input:
           ret.append( Do Something )
        return ret

    def fit(self, X_input=None, y=None):
        self.other_features_list = self.otherFeatures(X_input)
        return self

    def transform(self, X_input=None):
        X_output = self.otherFeatures(X_input)
        return X_output


feature_union = FeatureUnion([('TfIdf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9, ngram_range=(1, 4), strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2')),('OtherFeatures', OtherFeatures())])

km=KMeans(n_clusters=5, n_init=5,init='k-means++') 

feature_pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_union', feature_union),("km",km)]) 

km=feature_pipeline.fit(X1)
```

The pipeline calls the feature union and then kmeans clustering.

As I think about this does the line feature_pipeline.fit(X1) call the fit function of feature_union first and then the fit function of kmeans.

I am just returning the OtherFeatures class object in the fit function so what should be done in the transform function to use from fit function as in this case I have a numeric list.

Also when should the transform function be used?

Can I get an idea about how a feature union is to be used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one way which is to pass a model to the constructor of the feature union class and then fit it in the fit function and apply transform in the transform class for the model passed. Is there any other solution.

```
class OtherFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):       
    def __init__(self,model):
        self.model = model

    def other_features(self,input):
        ret = []
        for i in input:
           ret.append( Do Something )
        return ret

    def fit(self, X_input=None, y=None):
        self.other_features_list = self.other_features(X_input)
        self.model.fit(self.other_features_list,y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X_input=None):
        X_output = self.otherFeatures(X_input)
        X_output = self.model.transform(X_output)
        return X_output


km=KMeans(n_clusters=5, n_init=5,init='k-means++') 
km_inside=KMeans(n_clusters=5, n_init=5,init='k-means++') 
feature_union = FeatureUnion([('TfIdf', TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=0.9, ngram_range=(1, 4), strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2')),('OtherFeatures', OtherFeatures(km_inside))])

feature_pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_union', feature_union),("km",km)]) 

km=feature_pipeline.fit(X1)
```

Comment: Can we use 2 different `TfIdf` (1 for english text column, 1 for other language say Latex) along with numerical columns (like price, age etc etc)?